# This proof from the textbook that the number of columns of a matrix equals its rank plus its nullity does not make any sense...

Tags: linear-algebra

START PROOF

"Let A be an m $\times$ n matrix of rank r. Because A has rank r, you know it is row-equivalent to a reduced row-echelon matrix with nonzero rows. No generality is lost by assuming that the upper left corner of has the form of the r $\times$ r identity matrix I$_r$. Moreover, because the zero rows of contribute
nothing to the solution, you can discard them to form the r $\times$ n matrix, B', where B' is the augmented matrix [I$_r$ C]. The matrix C has n - r columns corresponding to the variables $x_{r+1}, x_{r+2}, ..., x_n$. So the solution space of Ax = 0 can be represented by the system:
[image]

Solving for the first variables in terms of the last variables produces vectors 
in the basis for the solution space, so the solution space has dimension n - r."

END PROOF

The above proof is from a textbook from a class on linear algebra I am taking through a distance-education program. What does not make any sense in this proof is how one can assume that the matrix that, when "row-operated", will produce a row-equivalent matrix, part of whose columns can form the identity matrix. This is not true so I am questioning the very generality that is assumed to hold true. What about this matrix shown in the previous page of the textbook:
[image]
Clearly, this matrix is in reduced row-echelon form, but part of the total columns just do not form the identity matrix. So I do need a clarification on how the statement "No generality is lost by assuming that the upper left corner of has the form of the r $\times$ r identity matrix I$_r$." is, in fact, generally applicable, because, in this matrix's case, it is not.

Answer (score 4):

If you swap the second and third columns in the row-reduction of your example $A$, you get a matrix with the $2\times2$ identity matrix in the upper-left-hand corner. Since swapping columns corresponds to a relabeling of variables, it won't change the rank or the nullity, so it doesn't affect the validity of the proof. In general, you will always be able to do this.

This is what is meant by "no generality is lost": not that the statement is always true of the original matrix, but that you can always transform the original matrix into one for which it is true, in a way that doesn't affect the truth of the theorem.